# Колода карт сека С++

Tags: c++, консоль

помогите пожалуйста, нужно сделать колоду карт из 21 карты от 9 до тузов, 9 только одна это треф, и что бы колода выводилась на экран

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>         
#include <ctime>            
using namespace std;
 
enum Suit { clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades };
 
const int jack = 11;      
const int queen = 12;       
const int king = 13;
const int ace = 14;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class card
   {
   private:
      int number;        //достоинство
      Suit suit;         //масти
   public:
      card()                    
         { }
      void set(int n, Suit s)     
         { suit = s; number = n; }
      void display();         
   };
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void card::display()              
   {
   if( number >= 2 && number <= 10 )
      cout << number;
   else
      switch(number)
         {
         case jack:  cout << "J"; break;
         case queen: cout << "Q"; break;
         case king:  cout << "K"; break;
         case ace:   cout << "A"; break;
         }
   switch(suit)
      {
      case clubs:    cout << static_cast<char>(5); break;  
      case diamonds: cout << static_cast<char>(4); break;  
      case hearts:   cout << static_cast<char>(3); break;  
      case spades:   cout << static_cast<char>(6); break;  
      }
   }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
   {
   card deck[52];
   int j, count = 1;
   cout << endl;
   for(j=0; j<52; j++)         
      {
      int num = (j % 13) + 2;  
      Suit su = Suit(j / 13);  
      deck[j].set(num, su);    
      }
   
   srand( time(NULL) );       
 
   char ans = 'y';
   do {
       cout << "Card #" << count << ": ";
       int k = rand() % 52;
       deck[k].display(); cout << endl;
       cout << "Do you want another card? (y/n)";
       cin >> ans;
   } while (ans == 'y');
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так - для мастей и значений использовать `enum`. Для вывода в консоль - дополнительные массивы символов. В примере колода из 52 карт, но думаю убрать лишнее - не проблема.

```
enum SuitCards : unsigned char { clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades }; // перечисление мастей
const string_view SuitCardsSymbol[] = { "♣", "♦", "♥", "♠"};  // символы мастей для вывода в консоль

enum ValueCards : unsigned char { two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace }; // перечисление значений
const string_view ValueCardsStr[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"}; // символы значений для вывода

struct PlayingCard
{
    SuitCards suit; // масть
    ValueCards value; // значение
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const PlayingCard &card)  // вывод карты в поток
{
    out << SuitCardsSymbol[card.suit] << ValueCardsStr[card.value];
    return out; 
}

int main()
{
    PlayingCard card{ SuitCards::clubs, ValueCards::ten};
    cout << "My card is " << card << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

А из имеющейся колоды делаете нужные сэты и пользуетесь.
Или вот так - карты обозначаются строками. Но так труднее с ними работать и проще ошибиться на мой взгляд. Но зато 1 карта = 1 строка. И выводится в поток без дополнительных функций.

```
vector<string> AllCards = { 
"♥2","♥3","♥4","♥5","♥6","♥7","♥8","♥9","♥10","♥V","♥D","♥K","♥T",
"♠2","♠3","♠4","♠5","♠6","♠7","♠8","♠9","♠10","♠V","♠D","♠K","♠T",
"♦2","♦3","♦4","♦5","♦6","♦7","♦8","♦9","♦10","♦V","♦D","♦K","♦T",
"♣2","♣3","♣4","♣5","♣6","♣7","♣8","♣9","♣10","♣V","♣D","♣K","♣T" };
// в вашем случае
vector<string> AllCards = { 
"♥10","♥V","♥D","♥K","♥T",
"♠10","♠V","♠D","♠K","♠T",
"♦10","♦V","♦D","♦K","♦T",
"♣9","♣10","♣V","♣D","♣K","♣T" };
```

А колоду проще всего задать изначально по порядку в каком-нибудь `vector<>`, а потом перемешать. Для этого есть функция стандартной библиотеки `random_shuffle()`. Это ещё удобнее для того, что при раздаче будете удалять  карту из контейнера и при последующей рандомной карте - эта карта не будет участвовать в раздаче.

Comment: Что делать если в консоле не отображаются масти

Comment: random_shuffle(AllCards.begin(), AllCards.end());
    for (auto i = AllCards.begin(); i != AllCards.end(); ++i){ cout << ' ' << *i; }

Comment: выводил вот так

Comment: и еще вопрос, мне нужно потом на 7 человек разложить эти карты и посчитать количество балов, например ♣10 ♣V ♣D это 30, "♣D ♣K ♣T это 31, тузы это 11 балов, ♣9 заменяет любую карту, все остальное 10 балов, как

Comment: можно чи посчитать так ?

Comment: Есть `vector<PlayingCard>` или `set<PlayingCard>`- это колода. Делаете `set<PlayingCard> Player[7]' - это карты у игроков. Забираете из колоды карту, кладете кому-то из игроков - вот и раздача. Подсчет тоже простой - по аналогии с массивом `ValueCardsStr[] = {"2",` делаете массив значений и обращаетесь к нему по индексу `CostCards[card.value]`. Это если использовать enum. А если делать со строками, то выбирать последний символ и писать свитч для получения стоимости. Я писал - с `enum` проще работать.